How do i do navigation with nav2 using a robot with namespaces?
i keep getting this [amr_1.global_costmap.global_costmap]: Sensor origin at (-7.29, 3.31) is out of map bounds (0.00, 0.00) to (4.98, 4.98). The costmap cannot raytrace for it. [planner_server-2] [WARN] [1721300547.714591131] [nav2_costmap_2d]: Robot is out of bounds of the costmap! message when trying to use nav2 navigation on my robot with namespace /amr_1. I am having trouble publishing the map, i dont know where to enter the path to the pgm map. I have done it with the map in a different simulation without namespace. Now i want to do a multirobot navigation simulation so i am starting by navigating only one robot with a namespace. Can any one help point me towards some good resources on multirobot navigation, or atleast help solve this error of global costmap. 
Here is the map without any problems from my simulation without namespace

In the screen shot above, you can see the global cost map is getting published partially and at a different location. I think this is because i havent published a map yet. I have tried publishing to the map topic using the online async launch in slam toolbox but the map keeps getting messed up for some reason. When i use map_start_at_dock: true, this is what happens.
I have even tried using a map server to directly publish the map. But the slam mapping will overwrite it after 2 seconds for some reason. Where do i put the path to the map file? and do i put the save file or yaml or serial?
Here is my nav2 params file:
/amr_1/amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "amr_1/base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "amr_1/odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: "scan"

/amr_1/amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

/amr_1/amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

/amr_1/bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: amr_1/base_link
    odom_topic: amr_1/odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

/amr_1/bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

/amr_1/bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

/amr_1/controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

/amr_1/local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: amr_1/odom
      robot_base_frame: amr_1/base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      filters: ["keepout_filter"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 2.58
        inflation_radius: 1.75
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /amr_1/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      keepout_filter:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::KeepoutFilter"
        enabled: True
        filter_info_topic: "/costmap_filter_info"
        mask: /home/tarun_56/pc_ws/keepout_mask.yaml
      always_send_full_costmap: True

/amr_1/global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      # width: 50.0  # Adjust to a suitable value
      # height: 50.0  # Adjust to a suitable value
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      map_topic: "map"
      robot_base_frame: amr_1/base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      filters: ["keepout_filter"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /amr_1/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 2.58
        inflation_radius: 0.6
      keepout_filter:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::KeepoutFilter"
        enabled: True
        filter_info_topic: "/costmap_filter_info"
        mask: /home/tarun_56/pc_ws/keepout_mask.yaml
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: ""

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

/amr_1/planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

/amr_1/smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

/amr_1/behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: amr_1/odom
    robot_base_frame: amr_1/base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

/amr_1/robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

/amr_1/waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

/amr_1/velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "amr_1/odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

Here is my navigation launch file for my first robot.
import os

from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch.actions
import launch_ros.actions
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, SetEnvironmentVariable
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_prefix
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from nav2_common.launch import RewrittenYaml


def generate_launch_description():
    proyecto_rosbot = get_package_share_directory('autobot')
    proyecto_nav2_bt_navigator = get_package_share_directory('nav2_bt_navigator')
    
    use_sim_time = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time',
                                                            default='true')
    autostart = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('autostart')
    params_file = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('params')
    default_bt_xml_filename = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
        'default_bt_xml_filename')


    # Create our own temporary YAML files that include substitutions
    param_substitutions = {
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'default_bt_xml_filename': default_bt_xml_filename,
        'autostart': autostart,
    }

    lifecycle_nodes = ['controller_server',
                       'planner_server',
                       'behavior_server',
                       'bt_navigator',
                       'waypoint_follower']

    configured_params = RewrittenYaml(
        source_file=params_file,
        param_rewrites=param_substitutions,
        convert_types=True)
    
    config = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('autobot'),
        'config',
        'nav2_params_amr_1.yaml'
        )
    

    return LaunchDescription([
        
        
        # Set env var to print messages to stdout immediately
        SetEnvironmentVariable('RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM', '1'),

        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time', default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'autostart', default_value='true',
            description='Automatically startup the nav2 stack'),

        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'params',
            default_value=[proyecto_rosbot,
                           '/config/nav2_params_amr_1.yaml'], #/config/nav2_params_sim_rosbot1.yaml
            description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'default_bt_xml_filename',
            default_value=os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory('nav2_bt_navigator'),
                'behavior_trees', 'navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml'),
            description='Full path to the behavior tree xml file to use'),
        
        # Importante que los nombres de los parametros en el .yaml sean iguales al nombre de los nodos, 
        # los nombres de los nodos acaban siendo namespace.name 

        launch_ros.actions.Node(         
            package='nav2_controller',
            executable='controller_server',
            name='controller_server',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1',  
            parameters=[config]
            ),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='nav2_planner',
            executable='planner_server',
            name='planner_server',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1',  
            parameters=[config]
            ),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='nav2_behaviors',
            executable='behavior_server',
            name='behavior_server',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1',
            parameters=[config],

            ),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='nav2_bt_navigator',
            executable='bt_navigator',
            name='bt_navigator',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1',
            parameters=[config,
                        {'default_bt_xml_filename', default_bt_xml_filename}],
            ),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='nav2_waypoint_follower',
            executable='waypoint_follower',
            name='waypoint_follower',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1', 
            parameters=[config],
            ),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='nav2_lifecycle_manager',
            executable='lifecycle_manager',
            name='lifecycle_manager_navigation',
            output='screen',
            namespace = 'amr_1', 
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time},
                        {'autostart': autostart},
                        {'node_names': lifecycle_nodes},
            ]),

    ])

Thankyou for the help in advance, I would appreciate it alot if you could point me to some good resource or reference for doing multirobot navigation aswell. If any other file is required for fixing it, please ask an i will respond as fast as possible. I have been working on the project for quite a while and on the verge of giving up.

If you check out Nav2 Bringup (make sure to set to the branch you're using the ROS distribution for), you'll see examples of how to setup Nav2 with namespacing in the context of multirobot simulations. If you only want a single robot, then that's just a simpler case of these launch file examples!
[1] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_bringup/launch

Alright thankyou, now ill just have to replace the world and my robots i believe.
